# Downloaded Images does not set as background always?

Tags: python, windows, random, ctypes, urllib

I am trying to download some images from  [MomentumDash](https://momentumdash.com/) (for educational purpose only).
I have written the following python code:

```
import urllib
import os
import random


#Chooses an image between 1 to 14
choice=random.randint(01,14)
print choice

#Downloads images
a=urllib.urlretrieve("https://momentumdash.com/backgrounds/"+"%02d" % (choice,)+".jpg", str(choice)+".jpg")
print a   #Tells the image

#Getting the location of the saved image
cwd = os.getcwd()
random=random.choice(os.listdir(cwd))
file =cwd+ '\\' +random

#Making the image to desktop image
import ctypes 
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER , 0, file, 3)
```

The thing is the probability of this progrm to set a image is 1/7 ish.
Most of the times it gives a black background screen.
Where am I wrong?

Comment: `os.listdir()` will give you a list of all files in a given directory - are there files other than the images you are downloading in your working directory? (hint: this python script)

Comment: Firstly use a different variable name for `random`, you are overwriting the library name. Secondly, print what you get for `os.listdir(cwd)`, chances are some of the entries are not suitable image files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. This ensures that the directory listing is filtered to give you only `jpg` files. A random entry is taken from these. Also `os.path.join()` is used to safely join your path and name together.

```
import urllib
import os
import random
import ctypes 

#Chooses an image between 1 to 14
choice = random.randint(1, 14)

#Downloads images
download_name = "{:02}.jpg".format(choice)
a = urllib.urlretrieve("https://momentumdash.com/backgrounds/{}".format(download_name), download_name)

#Getting the location of the saved image
cwd = os.getcwd()

#Filter the list to only give JPG image files
image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(cwd) if os.path.splitext(f)[1].lower() == ".jpg"]
random_image = random.choice(image_files)
full_path = os.path.join(cwd, random_image)

#Making the image to desktop image
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20 
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER , 0, full_path, 3)
```

The list of files is filtered by using Python's [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html?highlight=list%20comprehension#list-comprehensions) feature. This is a way of building a new list from an existing item. In this case it uses the optional `if` statement to only include files in the new list which have an extension of `.jpg`.

Comment: hadn't thought of forcing the extension to `.jpg`, +1

Comment: Wonderful answer! Can you please elaborate on this syntax in brief please?
`image_files = [f for f in os.listdir(cwd) if os.path.splitext(f)[1].lower() == ".jpg"]`

Comment: It is called a list comprehension which is a feature of the Python language. I have added a link in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
import urllib
import os
import random
import ctypes

# Set up an output folder
out_folder = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Backgrounds')

# Make it if it doesn't exist
if not os.path.isdir(out_folder):
    os.mkdir(out_folder)

# Loop through all values between 1 and 15
for choice in range(1,15):
    #Downloads images
    a = urllib.urlretrieve("https://momentumdash.com/backgrounds/" + "%02d" % (choice,)+".jpg",
                           os.path.join(out_folder, "{}.jpg".format(choice))
                           )

selected_wallpaper = random.choice(os.listdir(out_folder))

#Making the image to desktop image
SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 20
ctypes.windll.user32.SystemParametersInfoA(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, os.path.join(out_folder, selected_wallpaper), 3)
```

This creates a folder called `Backgrounds` in your current working directory, saves all the images there and then picks one at random.

Comment: Never thought of making a new folder, nice one!